# "Please wait until after injection has completed to use this object" error from Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice, circular-dependency

We have two singleton objects (declared via `in(Scopes.SINGLETON)`) in Guice that each uses the other in its constructor. Guice's way to implement this is with proxies - it initializes the object at first with a proxy to the other object, and only when that object is needed it is resolved.

When running this code from several threads, we get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is a proxy used to support
circular references involving constructors. The object we're proxying is not
constructed yet. Please wait until after injection has completed to use this
object.
    at
com.google.inject.internal.ConstructionContext$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(ConstructionContext.java:100)
```

I assume this is a bug in Guice, because we aren't doing anything out of the ordinary. One workaround we found is initializing the singletons early using `.asEagerSingleton()`, but this is not very convenient, for testing for example.

<s>Is this a known issue?</s> Reported an [issue with Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=550), reproduces with a standalone test.

Any other suggestions/workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try injecting a `Provider<T>` in each constructor instead of the actual instances?

If you don't need the other instance in the code of constructor, then just store the `Provider` to a final field, and use this field later on (by calling `get()`).

Comment: Yeah, I already tried this workaround and it works. Now the problem is detecting all the cases in my code where I have circular dependency and replacing them with a provider :(

Comment: BTW, note that the trunk version of Guice has this patch to disable circular proxies: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/detail?r=1151